# Cannot detect changes to clipboard

Tags: python, tkinter

The following is the original code where it will run python from a directory (virtual environment) to listen to the clipboard every 3 seconds and input the copy into the input, save as py and run py from there. The issue is it will run one instance of python every 3 seconds upon clicking on the 'autorun' option.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext, Menu, Checkbutton, Button, messagebox
import subprocess
import os
import threading
import time
import shutil

# Variable to keep track of the running thread
running_thread = None
auto_save_and_run = False
clipboard_data = ""
running_indicator = None  # Indicator for code execution status
clipboard_listener_enabled = True  # Indicates whether clipboard listener is enabled

def toggle_auto_save_and_run():
    global auto_save_and_run
    auto_save_and_run = not auto_save_and_run
    if auto_save_and_run:
        save_and_run_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    else:
        save_and_run_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def toggle_clipboard_listener():
    global clipboard_listener_enabled
    clipboard_listener_enabled = not clipboard_listener_enabled
    if clipboard_listener_enabled:
        clipboard_listener_button.config(text="Disable Active Clipboard Listening")
    else:
        clipboard_listener_button.config(text="Enable Active Clipboard Listening")

def execute_python_code():
    global clipboard_data
    code = code_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    try:
        if clipboard_data != code:
            # Save the code as 'guiscript.py' in the same directory
            with open('guiscript.py', 'w') as file:
                file.write(code)

            # Execute 'guiscript.py' using the subprocess.Popen method
            command = ["python", "guiscript.py"]
            process = subprocess.Popen(
                command, cwd=os.getcwd(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True
            )

            while True:
                output = process.stdout.readline()
                if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
                    break
                if output:
                    result_text.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                    result_text.insert(tk.END, output)
                    result_text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                    result_text.see(tk.END)
                    result_text.update_idletasks()

            process.stdout.close()
            process.wait()

            running_indicator.config(bg="red")
            clipboard_data = code  # Update clipboard_data
        else:
            result_text.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    except Exception as e:
        result_text.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        result_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        result_text.insert(tk.END, f"Error saving or running script: {str(e)}")
        running_indicator.config(bg="red")
    finally:
        save_and_run_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

def list_python_scripts():
    scripts_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    scripts_window.title("List of Python Scripts")
    script_listbox = tk.Listbox(scripts_window)
    script_listbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # List all *.py files in the current directory
    scripts = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".py")]
    for script in scripts:
        script_listbox.insert(tk.END, script)

    def on_script_selected():
        selected_index = script_listbox.curselection()
        if selected_index:
            selected_script = script_listbox.get(selected_index)
            # Get the content of the selected script
            with open(selected_script, 'r') as file:
                script_content = file.read()

            # Update the clipboard with the content of the selected script
            root.clipboard_clear()
            root.clipboard_append(script_content)

            # Close the list of Python scripts window
            scripts_window.destroy()

    copy_button = tk.Button(scripts_window, text="Copy Script to Clipboard", command=on_script_selected)
    copy_button.pack()

def update_result_text():
    global running_thread
    if running_thread is not None and running_thread.is_alive():
        result_text.after(100, update_result_text)
    else:
        result_text.see(tk.END)

def update_clipboard():
    global auto_save_and_run
    global clipboard_listener_enabled
    if clipboard_listener_enabled:
        clipboard_data = root.clipboard_get()
        if clipboard_data:
            code_entry.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            code_entry.insert(tk.END, clipboard_data)

            # Automatically save and run the code if auto-save and run is enabled
            if auto_save_and_run:
                save_and_run_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                threading.Thread(target=execute_python_code).start()  # Run in a separate thread
    root.after(3000, update_clipboard)

def confirm_exit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?"):
        root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Python Code Runner V1.02")

# Calculate window size to fill 70% of screen height and 50% of screen width
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
window_width = int(screen_width * 0.5)
window_height = int(screen_height * 0.7)

# Set window size and position it at the center of the screen
x_position = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
y_position = (screen_height - window_height) // 2
root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

menu_bar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

scripts_menu = Menu(menu_bar)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Scripts", menu=scripts_menu)
scripts_menu.add_command(label="List Python Scripts", command=list_python_scripts)

code_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Python Code:")
code_label.pack()

code_frame = tk.Frame(root)
code_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

code_entry = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(code_frame, height=10, width=40)
code_entry.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# Create the Auto Save and Run checkbox
auto_save_checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Enable Auto Save and Run", variable=auto_save_and_run, command=toggle_auto_save_and_run)
auto_save_checkbox.pack(side=tk.TOP)

# Create a color indicator for code execution status below the Save and Run button
running_indicator = tk.Canvas(button_frame, width=10, height=10, bg="red")
running_indicator.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

# Create a button to toggle clipboard listener
clipboard_listener_button = Button(root, text="Disable Active Clipboard Listening", command=toggle_clipboard_listener)
clipboard_listener_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

# Slightly adjust the position of the Save and Run button to the left
save_and_run_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Save and Run Code", command=execute_python_code)
save_and_run_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

result_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height=10, width=40, bg="black", fg="white")
result_text.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
result_text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

update_result_text()
update_clipboard()

# Set a callback for the window close button
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", confirm_exit)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to have that autorun, but only where there is changes in clipboard data, even though the autorun tick is enabled. If clipboard data is the same, it should not run. Is there any method to do that?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do what you want, and there doesn't need to be. Just save the value on the clipboard to a global variable, and compare it against the current value. If the current value is different from the previous value, run your code.

Here's a really simple little class that will do all of the work of watching the clipboard, and generate a single `<<ClipboardChanged>>` event whenever the clipboard changes. The clipboard contents will be copied to a text widget along with a timestamp.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

class ClipboardHistory(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.tag_configure("timestamp", background="gray90", underline=True)
        self.tag_configure("data", lmargin1=10, lmargin2=10, spacing1=10)
        self.clipboard_data = None
        self.configure(state="disabled")

    def auto_update(self, seconds=3):
        self.update_history()
        self.after(seconds*1000, self.auto_update, seconds)

    def update_history(self):
        new_clipboard_data = self.clipboard_get()
        if new_clipboard_data != self.clipboard_data:
            # clipboard data has changed
            current_yview = self.yview()
            self.clipboard_data = new_clipboard_data
            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
            self.configure(state="normal")
            self.insert("end", timestamp, "timestamp", "\n")
            self.insert("end", new_clipboard_data + "\n", "data")
            self.configure(state="disabled")
            # auto-scroll, if the user hasn't scrolled away from the bottom
            if current_yview[1] == 1:
                self.see("end")
            self.event_generate("<<ClipboardChanged>>")

root = tk.Tk()
ch = ClipboardHistory(root)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=ch.yview)
ch.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
ch.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

ch.auto_update()

root.mainloop()
```